# Can I use Yarn to run MapReduce jobs and web apps in the same cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

I realize that Yarn is a complete resource manager, that is no longer MapReduce specific. Does that mean that I can run web apps and MapReduce jobs in the same cluster? Can I, say, run 12 instances of an http service, and Yarn will fork and terminate them for me? If not, what would be a good cluster resource manager?

Answer (score 0):

i have same idea, and find a prototype implement of  [paas on haddop yarn](http://jaigak.blogspot.com/2012/07/paas-on-hadoop-yarn-idea-and-prototype.html). it's [github repository](https://github.com/jaigaksong/HadoopPaas) but can not find a real world practice.